# The Criteria of a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology

I would appreciate it if you could help me with a question on topology. I'm a beginner and studying on my own. In the following question 
Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions in a space $X = {f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}}$. Does
$d(f, g) =\max|f − g|$ define a metric?
I know that $d(f,g)$ does not satisfy the property $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$. According to the text, "if $|f (x) − g(x)| = 0$, this does not imply that $f = g$ because $f$ and $g$ could intersect at one, and only one, point."
I cannot understand the role of "max" here. $f$ and $g$ are functions and for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, we will have one $|f-g|$. And if $|f-g|=0$, it means $f=g$ over the whole $[0,1]$. It cannot occur at one single point. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course if $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ at some point $x\in [0,1]$ doesn't imply that $f$ and $g$ is the same function. But if the maximum is zero then it is something much stronger. The role of max is simple: you define the set $\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x\in[0,1]\}$ and you take its maximum. Note that $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is always non negative. So if the maximum if zero then for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $0\leq |f(x)-g(x)|\leq\max_{x\in[0,1]}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}=0$ and hence $f(x)=g(x)$. Since it is true **for all** $x\in [0,1]$ we conclude that $f=g$.